# Postgresql materialized view efficient with many refreshes?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

Does the postgresql materialize view rebuild the entire table on a REFRESH command? Is it efficient to TRIGGER a refresh to a materialized view that is dependent on a table with heavy writes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` will rebuild the whole materialized view.

It would be very inefficient to do that after every data modufication.

What you could do is to use a normal table instead of a materialized view and write a trigger that keeps the table updated.